# in codeigniter where is ci_sessions updated

Tags: codeigniter, session, tankauth

application uses codeigniter and tank_auth with it. I need to add some more data to add `ci_sessions` table. I could not find where a data is inserted to `ci_sessions`. Where it is, in which folder or controller or library?

Comment: I think link will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177742/how-does-codeigniter-know-a-cookie-holds-valid-session-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: it is in system/libraries/Session.php

but altering library tank_auth.php sounded better than Session.php

for similar questions: I changed this

```
$this->ci->session->set_userdata(array(
    'user_id'   => $user->id,
    'username'  => $user->username,
    'status'    => ($user->activated == 1) ? STATUS_ACTIVATED : STATUS_NOT_ACTIVATED,
                    ));
```

to this:

```
$this->ci->session->set_userdata(array(
     'user_id'  => $user->id,
     'username' => $user->username,
     'status'   => ($user->activated == 1) ? STATUS_ACTIVATED : STATUS_NOT_ACTIVATED,
     'language'  => $user->language,
                    ));
```

by adding `$user->language` with addition to the `language` column to `users` table in database.

the data is still stored in `ci_sessions` table but in `user_data` column.